# Big Sur Home.app suddenly requires iCloud Keychain

Tags: icloud, big-sur, homekit

I'm using the same set of connected devices in Home.app on two Macs (both on Big Sur), an iPhone and an iPad. All of a sudden, the Home app on one of the Macs prompts me to enable iCloud Keychain in order to use it (see the screenshot below). I never used iCloud Keychain, and I frankly rather wouldn't have my Keychain in the Cloud. I *do* use iCloud for Home.app.

The other Mac and the iDevices still work fine without iCloud Keychain, though.
Is there a way to get Home.app to work as before without iCloud Keychain?

[image]

Comment: I think it’s a requirement.
when you set up filevault did you save your key?
By default that’s now stored in iClouds Keychain automatically via installation.
Personally, I don't see any major issues with using Keychain its pretty secure and robust.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I did set up Filevault, but I didn't store the key in iCloud. I do like the usual system-wide Keychain, but I'd rather not have it in the Cloud. Call me old fashioned, but I prefer to keep my secrets on my computer ;)